# PHP Not Posting in SQL Database Insert Statement

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

So I'm attempting to gather data from a form in HTMl using the POST method and insert said data into a MySQL database using MySQLi functions. When in standalone PHP (without the database connection), I'm able to POST and echo data successfully to the second document.

However, once I open the connection to the database and attempt to use an insert statement, the data stops POSTing all together. I've tested the insert statement using strings, it works just fine.

Here's my form:

```
<form action="welcome" method="post">
    First Name*<br>
    <input type="text" name="userFN" required><br><br>
    Last Name*<br>
    <input type="text" name="userLN" required><br><br>
    Email*<br>
    <input type="email" name="userEmailAddress" required><br><br>
    Password*<br>
    <input type="password" name="userPassword" required><br><br>
    Tell Us About Yourself<br>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="userDescription">
    </textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Here's my PHP (welcome, as used in the action above).

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection

    if ($conn->connect_error) {

        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

    } 

    //post form info into variables
    $userFN = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['userFN']);
    $userLN = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['userLN']);
    $userEmailAddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['userEmailAddress']);
    $userPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['userPassword']);
    $userDescription = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['userDescription']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (userFN, userLN, userEmailAddress, userPassword, userDescription) VALUES" . " ('" . $userFN .  "','" . $userLN . "','" . $userEmailAddress . "','" . $userPassword . "','" . $userDescription . "');";

    echo $sql;

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

        echo "New record created successfully";

    } else {

        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;

    }
```

It **always** returns `New record created successfully`, and inserts a new record into the database, but all of the fields are blank. When I echo the insert statement, I get this:

`INSERT INTO users (userFN, userLN, userEmailAddress, userPassword, userDescription) VALUES ('','','','','');`

So it's clearly not getting my POST data anymore. I've tried using prepared statements and still no luck. What am I doing wrong here? I greatly appreciate any and all advice, thank you in advance.

Comment: is your entire code in the same file? and this action `action="welcome"` is that the actual? seems to be a folder named that, with an index file that should be inside it.

Comment: are you also successfully connected and to the right database?

Comment: Hello!

1) Form is in index.php, the rest is in /welcome/index.php as you stated.

2) I am, as stated in the OP, it will insert blank records in the database denoted with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and an AI surrogate ID. All other columns blank.

Comment: Write the sql to console / Page. Then copy the sql in a mysql cliënt, see If it works. It will also give you feedback, what what’s wrong with the sql.

Comment: I executed the statement in PhpMyAdmin and it worked just fine, populated all of the right columns. I even used the same statement in my document code using strings rather than PHP variables and it worked just fine. I just have no clue why it is no longer posting my form data.

Comment: If the sql is correct something is wrong with the way you setup your database connection. Where you write success, write the $conn->error see what is says. Is that === (?) correct, you can remove “=== TRUE”

Comment: Doing so had no change whatsoever. I seem to be connected to the database just fine, I'm able to create and drop tables, insert strings, etc.

Comment: @otsel goto chat.stackoverflow.com, I opened a chat room, will invite you once you are registered there. You need to visited it before I can invite.

Comment: if ($conn->query($sql) == TRUE) or if ($conn->query($sql))  triple = is not right

Comment: Is a var_dump($_POST) showing what you expect ?

Comment: @Roger Thanks for the offer, but it ended up working out! I definitely recommend you look into the === operator, it's quite useful!

Comment: @Otsel Have you checked the value of your `$_POST` variables???  That's the first place to look, whether your variables have data.  Then worry about the database.

Comment: @Eric, echoing the post data did nothing, as mentioned in the OP. The values were empty.

Comment: @otsel great that it works! I know the difference between == and ===. You need to be aware the *result* of query() depends on what your doing. Could be TRUE, FALSE *OR* a mysqli_result class. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: @Roger Understood, thanks again for your help!

Comment: @otsel great! please accept your own answer (yes you can), so the question doesn't show up as unanswered, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer may surprise you.

So the issue is actually in the form "action". Because of the way my webhosting provider is configured, I actually needed to specify `/index.php/` after the folder name in the action. It was actually confusing the server and for some reason translated to 'GET' instead of 'POST'. Hope this helps.

*Thanks for all the support!*